# Making a waster from wood board

Tags: hand-planing

I want to make a [waster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waster)/longsword from a 1x2 in board. I thought I could do this by taking a simple plane, and gradually planing out the blade until I have the right profile. It doesn't have to be perfect - if I wanted that, I'd buy one of the machined wasters available on the commercial market - but I want it to look somewhat like the real thing.

How can I ensure the proportions are correct? For example, a consistent taper on the blade, consistent profile, lack of asymmetry/skew (from overplaning one side)? The tapers are often very slight, so it is hard to gauge by eye if it's within line or not.

Is this something that you just have to have an eye for, or is there a trick to it? My only idea is to compare it to some reference between every stroke of the plane, but that would make it take 5-10x longer. Planing is a lot faster when I find a good position and rhythm of just doing it over and over, so I don't want to break that flow too often to go back and take measurements.

Disregard the handle and crossguard of the sword for this. I can figure those out. I'm only asking about the blade.

Comment: Before anything else are you sure you want to try to make something like this from a 1x2? Dimensional lumber is not dried well (it's wet enough that you really can't use it for anything other than framing work immediately after bringing it home), and this is one factor that makes it very prone to subsequent movement. In addition some SPF is just basically crap wood, not just soft but really very weak. If you must make it from 'pine' (generically, a softwood) you'd be much better off hand-selecting a board of clear pine or Douglas fir. Even so, as with all softwood swords, typically [contd]

Comment: ...the dimensions of the blade tend to be enlarged to make it more 'cartoony' for want of a better word. If you would prefer it to have dimensions and profiles closer to the real thing you'd be much better off making this from a close-grained hardwood, with soft or hard maple being strong contenders.

Comment: *"How can I ensure the proportions are correct?"* As with anything that you need to make to a given shape, marking out is your friend ;-) That way you can pretty much get into a rhythm in the planing and sort of go for it, although TBH there's not much planing to do here — this is perhaps a sub-10 minute job assuming good setup, a sharp plane and firm workholding, certainly shouldn't take longer than 20 mins.

Comment: I think graphus's time estimate may be off, especially for a new woodworker. Plan on it taking as long as is necessary.  I would also recommend getting multiple stock pieces to allow for early screw-ups. If you haven't tried hand-planing before, there are other Q/A here talking about how to sharpen and plane as well as plenty of videos.  Learning to plane takes practice, but can be a pleasure.

Comment: @Graphus I'm not following you on the 1x2... Where did I say I was using pine, softwood, or crap wood (if I did, I'd like to edit that and correct it)? Are you saying using a 1x2 is a bad idea because you're assuming the species of wood is inappropriate, or is there some other reason, such as it being too small to work with effectively?

Comment: @Graphus Also on the marking - thank you for the response, but this is too vague to be helpful. I can see that marking is useful. I'm asking how exactly I would measure and mark a tapered oval-ish profile. Maybe this isn't clear in the question? The point of the comments is supposed to be to suggest ways to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

To the OP, please understand that we use comments a little more loosely than other stacks.

I didn’t assume you were using construction lumber or that your 1x2 would have a moisture problem. Given hand work, I would probably avoid hard maple etc and lean toward poplar or something like it. It all depends on how much work this thing will do when done.

To mark the wide to a point curve (ie, the 1-1/2” face), find another smaller bit of wood that has a bit of spring to it and (probably with clamps holding the ends) mark it. I’d cut close to the line with a jigsaw to save time. You could plane one side to where you like it and then trace onto cardboard to get a template for the other side.

To put an edge on, mark the centerlines on 4 sides and plane to those.

Comment: Um, you might want to re-read the parenthetical comment in the third paragraph in light of the opening comments in para two.

Comment: @graphus — this might be a North American thing, but “2x” or “2 by 4” absolutely refers to construction lumber. On the other hand, 1x2 almost always refers to S4S non-construction lumber.

Comment: Aha, yes over here what we still refer to as 1x2s * is effectively an extension of construction wood and is sold alongside it (although we do have the equivalent of S4S of course, most commonly referred to as PAR, and this *may* be sold nominal, not actual). * Don't get me started on all the hangover imperial measurements peppered throughout various businesses and in common usage over here, even after all these decades of metric! It's so bad that most Brits, and the Irish too, refer to their weights and heights in imperial and can't even understand either in metric <le sigh>

Comment: I dunno about that, @AloysiusDefenestrate. My local Lowes & HD are filled with crapwood 1x2, 1x3 & 1x4. They're used for strapping where you don't need something pretty because it's going to be covered by something else. I used 1x2 to fur out studs in my new bathroom so I'd have enough clearance for plumbing... :shrug:

Comment: Don't you still measure fuel consumption in rods to the hogshead, @Graphus? :)

Comment: Until I actually went and checked, @freeman, I would’ve said that my local places don’t stock crappy 1x2. I was mistaken. I guess I’m always distracted by the crappy 1x4s.

Comment: @FreeMan, I wouldn't be surprised if *something* was still sold in some old obsolete measures, maybe up in the wilds of Scotland or on one of the islands.... after all, we do have, er, Silly isles :-))